# What is this electrical device with two wire terminals mounted to the outside of a junction box?

Tags: electrical, lighting

I found this electrical device above some ceiling panels and not sure what it is.

I'm planning on adding an additional light in this area and would like to at least be informed about what this device is.

I believe it's sitting above a junction box, but not sure what purpose it serves?

Any help is appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Doorbell or thermostat transformer.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Looks like a transformer. Might be a doorbell. If you have a helper, you could disconnect the wires (turn off the breaker first), and use a continuity tester to check if pressing the doorbell button closes the circuit. That's assuming you have a doorbell button (these get abandoned a lot so it may be unused). Also see if there is anything printed on the side of it. The word "Nutone" would be a quick give away.

Comment: Right. Doorbells and the occasional furnace accessory are about the only reasons you'd see one of that vintage. Doesn't look like there's a furnace nearby.

Comment: Definitely doorbell or furnace low voltage transformer most likely 24vac on that side the 120v is connected under the cover plate. Looking at the age I would guess door bell but that a second wire was added could be furnace.

Comment: The second wire is often for a second doorbell at (usually) a back door. Doorbell chimes that I've seen have a second terminal for an alternate ring. Usually the main door is a two-tone chime and the second door is a single chime. In that case the one wire side of the transformer would run direct to the chime's common terminal, and the two wires would run to the individual door push buttons and then back to the two terminals on the chime.

Comment: @EdBeal stashing the junction box in the ceiling in what looks like a finished area of the basement would be pretty strange (and might be against code).

Comment: @z4-tier, even today what you see is code compliant. Most door bells go to the chime and the front door goes to a striker that pulls up hits the top chime then falls and hits the bottom chime , the back door is wired to the chime that pulls to only 1 , or just dong so you knew if it was front door or back the buttons went to the chime not the transformer I have wires several hundred and probably remodeled as many homes electronic chimes use the same wiring today the power goes to the chime and the switches have front and back for different noises , internet connected have addresses same wires.

Comment: note that illuminated and multi-zone doorbell buttons have diodes in them, which fool a continuity check 50% of the time, so test in each polarity.